# Do I need footnotes in a Foreword if I cite something?

Tags: publications, citations, citation-style

Dear Colleagues and Stack Exchange Readers,

Hello. I am writing a Foreword for a colleague's scholarly monograph. I would like to quote from one of my own books, as well as from the recent memoir of a public statesman, and from a high-level meeting.

Forewords must be short, generally between 750 to 1,250 words. I want mine to be about 900 words.

I have not seen any footnotes in other published Forewords. What do you think? Do I need to put in formal footnotes for this memoir and for my own book and the meeting, or is it appropriate to just put the title of the memoir or book in italics within the body of the Foreword, with the year of publication in parentheses after the title?

I would like to cite a brief phrase from the minutes of a high-level White House meeting. These records were published. Do I put in a full footnote with the source, or some kind of truncated, inline reference?

If you can share your thoughts on this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is the monograph book-length? If so, why should a forward be that short?

Comment: Please answer the question. Footnotes in a Foreword? (Yes, it's a book).

Comment: Yes, of course. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

First, to make it clear, if you use something you need to cite it. I'm sure you agree with that. The question is about how to do the citation.

For a book, I assume that there is an editor involved who will make decisions about such things as layout etc. If the book is being self-published by your colleague, then they might take on that task. But it is almost certainly someone besides yourself responsible for such things.

Thus, I would submit your Foreword with complete citations. Whether inline or in footnotes is immaterial. But they need to be complete (not just referencing a book in general). The editor can then take what you give them and format appropriately. If you make them complete then the editor will have everything they need to do the job correctly.

For what it's worth, I have seen footnotes in Forewords, but in a book length monograph, your length restriction seems rather short.

Comment: Thanks.It's a Foreword, not a "forward".